# MySQL Pivot Query to existing table

Tags: mysql, pivot

I am trying to create a query that will enter data from one existing table into another existing table. There are no common id fields between the two.

I have the following existing table t1

```
    ----------+------+-------+
    |user | criteria | record|
    ----------+------+-------+   
    | 1    | 11      | K     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 1    | 12      | L     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 1    | 13      | M     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 1    | 16      | P     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 1    | 18      | R     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 1    | 20      | T     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 2    | 11      | K     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 2    | 12      | L     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 2    | 13      | M     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 2    | 16      | P     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 2    | 18      | R     |
    ----------+------+-------+
    | 2    | 20      | T     |
    ----------+------+-------+
```

There are a large amount of users and (out of about 100 criteria) 6 criteria
I am interested in inserting into the following, existing table

```
 table t2

 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 | Label u  | Label v  | Label w  | Label x  | Label y  | Label z |
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 | record K | record L | record M | record P | record R  | record T|
 | record K | record L | record M | record P | record R  | record T|
 +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+

 where Criteria number 11 = Label u
       Criteria number 12 = Label v
       Criteria number 13 = Label w
       Criteria number 16 = Label x
       Criteria number 18 = Label y
       Criteria number 20 = Label z

 Note* Line 1 in t2 corresponds to user 1
       Line 2 in t2 corresponds to user 2

       There is no "user" column in t2 for the fields "user 1, user 2"

       t2 already contains data in other columns
```

t1 user is the same as a column in t2 for user. Data inserted from t1 for t1 user has to match data already in t2 for the same user.

My final query came out as this (which does not work)

```
INSERT INTO t2 a
  SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 11,record,NULL)) AS Label_u,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 12,record,NULL)) AS Label_v,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 13,record,NULL)) AS Label_w,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 14,record,NULL)) AS Label_x,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 15,record,NULL)) AS Label_y,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 16,record,NULL)) AS Label_z
  FROM mytable b
  WHERE a .user field = b.user
  GROUP BY USER
  ORDER BY USER;;

       I have tried many - Can someone help me find a functional query to do this?
```

Comment: Did you try writing anything? Do you have any code to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to design this query where additional fields can be updated simultaneously from tc and tr - This answer applies where tc.a = tr.cid and tr.cid = t1.user

```
SELECT ' Label_u'
  ,' Label_u'
  ,' Label_v'
  ,' Label_w'
  ,' Label_x'
  ,' Label_y'
  ,' Label_z'
  ,(SELECT `record` FROM `t1` WHERE `user` = b.id AND `criteria` = 11)
  ,(SELECT `record` FROM `t1` WHERE `user` = b.id AND `criteria` = 12)
  ,(SELECT `record` FROM `t1` WHERE `user` = b.id AND `criteria` = 13)
  ,(SELECT `record` FROM `t1` WHERE `user` = b.id AND `criteria` = 16)
  ,(SELECT `record` FROM `t1` WHERE `user` = b.id AND `criteria` = 18)
  ,(SELECT `record` FROM `t1` WHERE `user` = b.id AND `criteria` = 20)
  FROM tc a
     , tr b
  WHERE a .id = b .cid 
    AND b .print_id IS NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Pivot Table. You can remove the 2. line if you don´t want to have the user id

```
SELECT
  user,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 11,record,NULL)) AS Label_u,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 12,record,NULL)) AS Label_v,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 13,record,NULL)) AS Label_w,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 14,record,NULL)) AS Label_x,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 15,record,NULL)) AS Label_y,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF (criteria = 16,record,NULL)) AS Label_z
FROM mytable
WHERE user IN (1,2)
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY USER;
```

Result

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| user | Label_u | Label_v | Label_w | Label_x | Label_y | Label_z |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1 | P1      | P1      | P1      | P1      | R1      | T1      |
|    2 | P2      | P2      | P2      | P2      | R2      | T2      |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB >
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I pivot the results into an already created table 2 (t2) without entering the user - just Label_u | Label_v | Label_w | Label_x | Label_y | Label_z

Comment: Sorry i not understand. Do you have a second table (t2) and you want to sore the result in it? have the second table the user field ? try: insert into t2 SELECT .........the first query....;

Comment: That's alright, thank you! I have a second table I want to store the result in. It does not contain the user field.

Comment: Or you create a VIEW. Put this before my first Query. CREATE VIEW myt2 AS

Comment: remove the second line (user,) from my first query and put the before the query. INSERT INTO t2

Comment: This works very well. Thank you. There is one more component I have found to match the inserted values to the values already in the table that they belong with. t1 user is the same as column in t2 for user. (both come from a 3rd table's ID column)